# Can I use a procedure to store history log before ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Can I use a procedure to store history log before ON DELETE CASCADE(user, orders) ?

I am thinking I want to delete orders associated with users when we/they delete their accounts.  I'm not convinced this is the best procedure(as the orders table should be its own entity), however I would like to know if it's possible to step in and log each order(history) to a txt file or another table.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about file, but can store history data in another table using trigger. Here is the code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LOGORDERS
ON USERS
INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS
    DECLARE @UID INT
    SELECT @UID = UserID FROM DELETED
   INSERT INTO OrderLog(OrderItemName, UserID) SELECT OrderItemName, UserID FROM ORDERS  WHERE UserID = @UID
   DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE UserID = @UID

   DELETE FROM USERS WHERE UserID = @UID
GO
```